# How to Retrieve JSON data in web service received from Client side

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, rest

i am sending JSON data from Android phone to Restful web service and want to get that Data and store in database. How can i get data on server side when a request received from the Android Client.

i am using this

```
JSONObject holder = new JSONObject(); 
holder.put("Mukesh", "hi Micky"); 
holder.put("Waseem", "hi Waseem"); 
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(holder.toString()); 
postrequest.setEntity(entity); 
postrequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
postrequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

and accessing through this URL `<ip_address_to_my_server>:8080/RestFulWS/rest/hello` where `hello` is the class name

Comment: How are you sending the data? AJAX, JSONP? Or are you just hitting a URL?

Comment: i am using this                                                 `JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();  
holder.put("Mukesh", "hi Micky");  
holder.put("Waseem", "hi Waseem");  
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(holder.toString());  
                  
postrequest.setEntity(entity);  
postrequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
postrequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");`  and accessing through this URL  http://10.99.18.62:8080/RestFulWS/rest/hello     where hello is Class name

Comment: It's pretty vague. If you're just asking how to get the data sent by your client, you could just `request.getParameter()`, and if you're using any other technology you will have appropriate way to _get_ the data sent. If you're asking how to convert JSON object to a Java object that another question. Please be detailed.

Comment: Ok then plz tell me what is the proper way to send data from android Client and then get that data in web service. I want to send simple message, Images and Videos from Client (Android) to Server using web service.